# How to highlight text in a text input placeholder in angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am trying to highlight the searched text in an angular material site.

I am using a pipe like this:

```
export class HighlightSearch implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(value: any, args: any): any {


        if (!args) {
            return value;
        }

        if (args.length < 1) {
            return value;
        }
        // Match in a case insensitive maneer
        const re = new RegExp(args, 'gi');
        const match = value.match(re);

        // If there's no match, just return the original value.
        if (!match) {
            return value;
        }

        const replacedValue = value.replace(re, "<mark style='background-color: #FAA50A; padding:0em;'>" + match[0] + "</mark>");
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(replacedValue);
}
}
```

In the component I am using the pipe as:

```
<mat-label class="combobox-label" [innerHTML]="cstic.label | highlight: searchInput"></mat-label>
```

This works.

working highlight

[image]

But when I am trying to highlight the searched text in a placeholder it does not work...

I tried to use it like this:

```
<input matInput  [placeholder]="cstic.label | highlight: searchInput" value={{cstic.assignedValue}}
                     [(ngModel)]="cstic.assignedValue" />
```

But I am getting the following result:

not working highlight

[image]

Does anybody have a better idea how can I solve this?

Comment: have you tried any side library like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-text-highlight)

Comment: @shashanksharma tried the library but does not work in my case.

Comment: @Awais I've read the posted question but also no result with that. My code works for labels but is not working for this particular case when I want to mark a placeholder.

Comment: Then you need to create a [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/) example of your code

Comment: here you can find a small example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvrjnd

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I deleted the placeholder from the input field and added a label which behaves exactly the same as the placeholder but the highlight works for it.

So instead of this code:

```
<mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder={{cs.label}} [disabled]="cs.readOnly" value={{cs.value}}
                    [(ngModel)]="cs.assignedValue"                 [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" >
                <mat-label [innerHTML]="cs.label | highlight: searchInput">{{cs.label}} 
                 </mat-label>
            </mat-form-field>
```

I've put this one:

```
<mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [disabled]="cs.readOnly" value={{cs.value}}
                    [(ngModel)]="cs.assignedValue"                 [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" >
                <mat-label [innerHTML]="cs.label | highlight: searchInput">{{cs.label}} 
                 </mat-label>
            </mat-form-field>
```